# An equivalence of ".schema sqlite_master" in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite, data-dictionary

I'm trying to do the same exercise for both SQLite and Oracle. In SQLite, there is a table `sqlite_master` containing a description of all of the other tables, indexes, triggers, and views that are contained within the database. I can see the query to generate `sqlite_master` with `.schema sqlite_master`.

In Oracle, the data dictionary is presented to us in the form of a number of views (`DBA`, `ALL` or `USER`). Let's take the table `USER_TABLES` as an example. We can do query on `USER_TABLES`, for example

```
SELECT table_name
FROM USER_TABLES;
```

Is there anyway to get the query used to create the table `USER_TABLES` in Oracle? I tried

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'USER_TABLES')
FROM dual;
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are you looking for but if you want the definition of any table in oracle you can use :

```
Describe TableName
```

Or if you want to have list of tables, views or columns you can use below queries:
**For Tables :**

```
select * from select * from all_tables
```

**For Columns :**

```
select * from all_tab_columns
```

**For Views :**

```
select * from select * from all_views
```

**To get all the column information of a table:**
select *

```
 from all_tab_columns
 where upper(table_name) = upper('Test')
 order by column_id
```

Typically oracle stores table_name in uppercase so I used upper() or you can just type 'TEST'

Comment: It seems to me that SQL Developer does not allow `Describe `.

Comment: you can query all_tab_columns to have those information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this one:

```
DECLARE
   DDL  CLOB;
BEGIN
   FOR aTab IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES) LOOP
      DDL := DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', aTab.TABLE_NAME);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DDL);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

You may customize the output with `DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM()` before you run the query.